# Как добавить элемент в массив AngularJS/Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Пытаюсь добавить новый элемент в массив. Массив `$scope.messages` имеет вид:

```
37: Object
38: Object 
   dialog: "534_544"
   from: "534"
   message: "sfsnfsiofsiofnosfiosf"
   read: "0"
   time: "1428772580"
   to: "544"
 ...
 39: Object
```

Для этого пробовал:

Получить один из элементов массива из `$scope.messages`:
`$scope.messages[38]` и добавить его в этот же массив по номером 40, на что Angular выдает много ошибок в консоли.

```
var a = [];
a[40] = $scope.messages[38];
$scope.messages.push(a);
```

Изначальная задача добавить новый элемент в `ng-repeat="message in messages"` то бишь в массив: `messages`

Еще раз о структуру объекта `$scope.messages`:

```
 `1: Object 
dialog: "534_544"
from: "534"
message: "Test mEssage"
read: "0"
time: "1428852706"
to: "544"`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, что проблема в том, что `a` массив элементов. Это

```
var a = [];
a[40] = $scope.messages[38];
$scope.messages.push(a);
```

не добовлает `$scope.messages[38]` в `$scope.messages` номером 40, а добавляет массив `a` номером 40.

Наверно хочешь делать вот так

```
$scope.messages.push($scope.messages[38]);
```

или, если хочешь добавить именно номером 40, вот так

```
$scope.messages[40] = $scope.messages[38];
```

Comment: Выдает много ошибок - причем не ясно, к чему они относятся: `TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at l.angular.module.directive.directive.service.service.factory.factory.directive.directive.controller.controller.controller.controller.controller.controller.controller.directive.controller.controller.controller.service.controller.controller.controller.controller.controller.factory.factory.factory.controller.controller.controller.$scope.sendMessage`

Comment: Ты уверен, что они связанные с этим массивом? Создай пример на [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), чтобы лучше показать ситуацию.

Comment: Еще раз - вот такой объект в `$scope.messages`: добавил в вопрос

Answer (score -1):

`$scope.sendMessage` не объявлен ранее как массив, ошибку спровоцировал метод push

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение?